# Can I lock up CO2 into silicon carbide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, geochemistry

Can it be possible to use atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ in a reaction (or series) with silicon dioxide, both of which are plentiful, to sequester the carbon in a solid and more useful material, silicon carbide?

Comment: You seem to be missing the very point of the problem. The question is **not** _"what compounds of carbon are more useful or less harmful than CO2"_ (there are thousands of possible answers to that, and SiC is in no way exceptional or interesting). The question is _"where are the money"_.

Comment: The issues with carbon sequestration are usually economic not chemical. One of the better ideas (because it is easy and cheap to do) is to grow biomass and then turn it into charcoal. This can be buried to permanently sequester the carbon. No complicated chemistry required.

Comment: @matt_black only slightly better idea is to not burn coal in the first place.

Comment: @A.K. True, but it is a little late for that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not practically.

The reduction of silica and carbon dioxide to silicon carbide is a conducted at high temperatures (commonly higher than 1500 °C, reaching 2500 °C). The energy required to reach these temperatures is immense. Furthermore, this is done in a nearly pure carbon dioxide atmosphere. I remind you that our atmosphere has about 400 ppm of carbon dioxide.

Silica is not abundant as you think. The main source for silica, sand, is actually quite rare and many countries are experiencing environmental damage due to illegal or legal mining of sand. Sand is commonly host to fragile and unique ecosystems. You can mine sandstone, but you will need to crush it to sand. Pulverising is the most energy intensive phase of any mining operation. For silicon carbide to form efficiently, it has to be crushed to a fine powder. Sand size is not enough. This is extremely energy intensive.

This is going to be an extremely expensive undertaking, and since the source of most of our energy is still fossil fuels, then this would be counter productive.

Comment: Silica is common as are other silicates. High quality, pure silica for glassmaking or electronics is what we are short of.

Comment: @matt_black doesn't really matter. You want a carbon sink, not to make a new Intel chip. Even if it's 90% pure, good enough to put the carbon in. However, this is so energy intensive you will probably release more carbon to the atmosphere than sequester in the carbide.

Comment: I wish we could do it in desert. There are plenty of sand and sun. If we could build a robot to manufacture silicon carbide with solar power, print it into a building structure or building module. I don't know if it could replace concrete but it would be great if it can